# I want to use the sum function to count multiple occurrences of specific characters, but my script only works for one character

Tags: python, function, for-loop, variables, sum

This script is supposed to calculate the total weight of a protein, so I decided to count the occurrences of certain characters in a script. However, only the first equation produces a result which causes the total weight to be the same value (everything under the first one equals zero, which is definitely incorrect). How do I get my script to pay attention to the other lines???
This is a shortened version:

```
akt3_file = open('AKT3 fasta.txt', 'r') #open up the fasta file

for line in akt3_file:

   ala =(sum(line.count('A') for line in akt3_file)*89*1000) #this value is 1780000
   arg =(sum(line.count('R') for line in akt3_file)*174*1000)
   asn =(sum(line.count('N') for line in akt3_file)*132*1000)
   asp =(sum(line.count('D') for line in akt3_file)*133*1000)
   asx =(sum(line.count('B') for line in akt3_file)*133*1000)

protein_weight = ala+arg+asn+asp+asx
print(protein_weight) # the problem is that this value is also 1780000
akt3_file.close() #close the fasta file
```

Comment: @Blckknght's answer is what you want for this specific case. Now if you may need to count other characters in the future, try `collections.Counter`, it is specifically designed for this and is a character counter when a string is passed to its initializer.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you have is that you're trying to iterate over your file's lines several times. While that's actually possible (unlike most iterators, file objects can be rewound with `seek`), you're not doing it properly, so all the iterations except for the first don't see any data.

In this case, you probably don't need to iterate over the lines at all. Just read the full text of the file into a string, and count the characters you want out of that string:

```
with open('AKT3 fasta.txt', 'r') as akt_3file:  # A with is not necessary, but a good idea.
    data = akt_3file.read()        # Read the whole file into the data string.

ala = data.count('A') * 89 * 1000  # Now we can count all the occurrences in all lines at
arg = data.count('R') * 174 * 1000 # once, and there's no issue iterating the file, since
asn = data.count('N') * 132 * 1000 # we're not dealing with the file any more, just the
asp = data.count('D') * 133 * 1000 # immutable data string.
asx = data.count('B') * 133 * 1000
```